# Any possible solution to fix this warning in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I try to upload my app in app store with as usual method.But one week before i upgrade my xcode to 7.My project in swift 2.0 While validate i got an warning message that:

```
The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an informational message
```

So i leave that warning because its just a warning message. But after upload to app store .My itunes status was still in processing. I changes version number & re-archive ,but no use.All my status is in processing. How to fix this bug . how can i submit my app to app store.

```
Hyper.app 1.0(1)  (processing)
Hyper.app 1.0.2(1)  (processing)
Hyper.app 1.0(2)  (processing)
Hyper.app 2.0(1)  (processing)
Hyper.app 2.0(2)  (processing)
```

This is only showing in my itunes

Any possible solution will be appreciated !

Comment: If you still have these problem see this link.This will be use full                            https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18493

Comment: its look like my need in this forums